# GAE apps development: NullPointerException when returning a hashmap

Tags: java, google-app-engine, dictionary

Basically the user submit the year selected, and then the servlet returns the according annual report.
Then the user can modify the according information. then the servlet save the information modified.

Assume the stud the user looks for always exist in the em. The problem is:
If the user doesn't store annual report information before, and the user submit one year i.e. 2009, everything runs OK. user modifies the infomration and GPAInfoServlet will store the information modified.

However, after finishing the action above, which means the user stored one annual report information before, the user(which means me) gets ERROR **NullPointerException** during the process submitting the year selected

```
at tcndata.Stud.jdoGetannualReport(Stud.java)
at tcndata.Stud.getAnnualReport(Stud.java:33)
at servlet.YearSelectedServlet.doPost(YearSelectedServlet.java:35)
```

Select Year:

```
public class YearSelectedServlet extends HttpServlet {
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    int yearselected = Integer.parseInt(req
            .getParameterValues("yearselected")[0]);
    long studid = Long.parseLong(req.getSession().getAttribute("studID")
            .toString());

    EntityManager em;
    em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();

    Stud stud = em.find(Stud.class, studid);

    if (stud != null) {
        Map<Integer, AnnualReport> annualreport;
        if (stud.getAnnualReport() == null)
            annualreport = new HashMap<Integer, AnnualReport>();
        else
            annualreport = stud.getAnnualReport();

        if (annualreport.containsKey(yearselected)) {
            AnnualReport thatyear = stud.getAnnualReport()
                    .get(yearselected);
            req.getSession().setAttribute("thatyear", thatyear);
            req.getSession().setAttribute("annualReport", thatyear);
        }
    } else {
        req.getSession().setAttribute("Error", "alumni not found");
        resp.sendRedirect("Error.jsp");
    }
    req.getSession().setAttribute("yearselected",
            req.getParameterValues("yearselected")[0]);
    req.getSession().setAttribute("SearchTag", "GPAInfo");
    resp.sendRedirect("Search.jsp");

}
```

}

Save information modified:

```
public class GPAInfoServlet extends HttpServlet {
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {

    AnnualReport thatyear = new AnnualReport();

    thatyear.setAttendSchool(AttendSchool.valueOf(req
            .getParameterValues("AttendSchool")[0]));
    .....

    int yearselected = Integer.parseInt(req.getSession()
            .getAttribute("yearselected").toString());
    long studid = Long.parseLong(req.getSession().getAttribute("studID")
            .toString());

    EntityManager em;
    em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    Stud stud = em.find(Stud.class, studid);

    if (stud != null) {
        Map<Integer, AnnualReport> annualreport;
        if (stud.getAnnualReport() == null)
            annualreport = new HashMap<Integer, AnnualReport>();
        else
            annualreport = stud.getAnnualReport();

        annualreport.put(yearselected, thatyear);

        try {
            stud.setAnnualReport(annualreport);
            em.merge(stud);
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }

    } else {
        req.getSession().setAttribute("Error", "alumni not found");
        resp.sendRedirect("Error.jsp");
    }

    req.getSession().setAttribute("SearchTag", "GPAInfo");
    resp.sendRedirect("/Search.jsp");

}
```

}

Stud class:

```
@Entity( name = "Stud")
public class Stud{
    @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long studID;

private Map<Integer,AnnualReport>annualReport = new HashMap<Integer,AnnualReport>();

public Map<Integer, AnnualReport> getAnnualReport() {
    return annualReport;
}

public void setAnnualReport(Map<Integer, AnnualReport> annualReport) {
    this.annualReport = annualReport;
}
```

**I have no ideas what happens.

I already @Embeddable in annualreport:

```
@Embeddable
```

public class AnnualReport{

```
@Basic
private AttendSchool attendSchool;
private String attendSchoolNote;

......
```

}

How can I get **NullPointerException** in ** if (stud.getAnnualReport() == null) **

```
if (stud != null) {
        Map<Integer, AnnualReport> annualreport;
        if (stud.getAnnualReport() == null)
            annualreport = new HashMap<Integer, AnnualReport>();
        else
            annualreport = stud.getAnnualReport();

        ....
    } else {
        ....
    }
```

**NullPointerException**?

Need helps.... 
I am dying...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that line `annualreport = stud.getAnnualReport();` is where you get NPE?

Because a few lines lower you have code that surely produces NPE if `stud.getAnnualReport()` is `null`:

```
AnnualReport thatyear = stud.getAnnualReport()
                .get(yearselected);
```

Comment: YES, I am sure. Why thatyear = stud.getAnnualReport().get(yearselected); produces NPE?
if (stud.getAnnualReport() == null)
    then   annualreport = new HashMap<Integer, AnnualReport>();
then annualreport.containsKey(yearselected) is false,
then  thatyear = stud.getAnnualReport()
                .get(yearselected); can not be executed, right?